# REST access to Magento 2 (OAuth) with Delphi

Tags: rest, delphi, magento, oauth

we try to develop an interface for Magento 2.1 in Delphi XE6.
Before Magento 2 we used SOAP but with changes in the API since Magento 2, we think this is not the best solution anymore.

Our problems:
We created and activated an integration in Magento with all necessary rights.
Now we get consumer key, consumer secret, access token and access token secret.

We have a RESTClient, RESTRequest, RESTResponse and a OAuth1Authenticator. The authenticator gets both tokens and both secrets.
We adjust the properties for Accept, AcceptCharset and AcceptEncoding.

If we put a GET-Request to http://192.168.200.108/index.php/rest/V1/orders/1 everything is fine and we get the first order, which was placed in the shop.
The IP 192.168.200.108 is a standard installation of Magento in a virtual machine in our local network.

If we want to get a filtered list of orders via
 http://192.168.200.108/index.php/rest/V1/ordersindex.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2017-06-01%2000:00:00&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gt, we get "invalid signature" as response.
But with the REST extension for Firefox we get a valid filtered list of orders with the same URL.

Signature method of the authenticator is HMAC_SHA1. We compared both requests (Firefox and Delphi) via Wireshark, but both look equal.
Delphi encodes the brackets via url encoding, the REST extension in Firefox doesn't. If we tell the RESTClient in Delphi, that the URL is already encoded, Delphi doesn't encode the brackets but we get an HTML error 400 with "Bad request".

```
  OAuth1Authenticator1.ConsumerKey := sCONSUMER_KEY;
  OAuth1Authenticator1.ConsumerSecrect := sCONSUMER_SECRET;
  OAuth1Authenticator1.AccessToken := sACCESS_TOKEN;
  OAuth1Authenticator1.AccessTokenSecret := sACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET;

  RestClient2.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate';
  RESTRequest2.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate';

  RestClient2.Accept := '*/*';
  RESTRequest2.Accept := '*/*';

  RESTClient2.AcceptCharset := 'UTF-8';
  RESTRequest2.AcceptCharset := 'UTF-8';

  RESTClient2.BaseURL := 'http://192.168.200.108/';
  RESTRequest2.Params.Clear;

  RESTRequest2.Resource := 'index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2016-07-01 00:00:00&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gt'; 

  RESTRequest2.Method := rmGET;

  RESTRequest2.Params.Clear;
  RESTRequest2.Params.AddItem;
  RESTRequest2.Params[0].name := 'private_content_version';
  RESTRequest2.Params[0].Value := 'c6f9e0919d7028c78ee63e79593ef689';
  RESTRequest2.Params[0].ContentType := ctTEXT_PLAIN;
  RESTRequest2.Params[0].Kind := pkCOOKIE;
  RESTRequest2.Params[0].Options := RESTRequest2.Params[0].Options + [poDoNotEncode];

  RESTRequest2.Params.AddItem;
  RESTRequest2.Params[1].name := 'mage-messages';
  RESTRequest2.Params[1].Value := '%5B%5D';
  RESTRequest2.Params[1].ContentType := ctTEXT_PLAIN;
  RESTRequest2.Params[1].Kind := pkCOOKIE;
  RESTRequest2.Params[1].Options := RESTRequest2.Params[1].Options + [poDoNotEncode];

  RESTRequest2.Params.AddItem;
  RESTRequest2.Params[2].name := 'Accept-Language';
  RESTRequest2.Params[2].Value := 'null';
  RESTRequest2.Params[2].ContentType := ctTEXT_PLAIN;
  RESTRequest2.Params[2].Kind := pkHTTPHEADER;
  RESTRequest2.Params[2].Options := RESTRequest2.Params[2].Options + [poDoNotEncode];

  RESTRequest2.Params.AddItem;
  RESTRequest2.Params[3].name := 'DNT';
  RESTRequest2.Params[3].Value := '1';
  RESTRequest2.Params[3].ContentType := ctTEXT_PLAIN;
  RESTRequest2.Params[3].Kind := pkHTTPHEADER;
  RESTRequest2.Params[3].Options := RESTRequest2.Params[3].Options + [poDoNotEncode];

  RESTRequest2.Params.AddItem;
  RESTRequest2.Params[4].name := 'Connection';
  RESTRequest2.Params[4].Value := 'keep-alive';
  RESTRequest2.Params[4].ContentType := ctTEXT_PLAIN;
  RESTRequest2.Params[4].Kind := pkHTTPHEADER;
  RESTRequest2.Params[4].Options := RESTRequest2.Params[4].Options + [poDoNotEncode];

  RESTRequest2.Execute;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(RESTResponse2.Content);
```

Here the requests tracked with Wireshark.

Delphi:

```
GET /index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria%5Bfilter_groups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=created_at&searchCriteria%5Bfilter_groups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=2016-07-01%2000:00:00&searchCriteria%5Bfilter_groups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcondition_type%5D=gt HTTP/1.1
Accept-Language: null
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="5cbx1us6n7tpn5iv0a33p6iyq0otupsp", oauth_nonce="D4F1CF6F5DBB4F833D6CE644D3C20D95", oauth_signature="iXk6yBvuasDKnbdcxfATSQRJ%2BEg%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1496824715", oauth_token="nvoankn2g8jraga3k22ax9eyf55lqk9e", oauth_version="1.0"
Host: 192.168.200.108
Accept: */*
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, identity
User-Agent: Embarcadero RESTClient/1.0
Cookie: mage-messages=%5B%5D; private_content_version=c6f9e0919d7028c78ee63e79593ef689
```

Firefox:

```
GET /index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2016-07-01%2000:00:00&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gt HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.200.108
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: null
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_nonce="5xayplNhc6EVeoM", oauth_timestamp="1496824768", oauth_consumer_key="5cbx1us6n7tpn5iv0a33p6iyq0otupsp", oauth_token="nvoankn2g8jraga3k22ax9eyf55lqk9e", oauth_signature="Vl8tCEx%2F3abTjQFcxSfWcpzQ%2FHE%3D"
Cookie: private_content_version=c6f9e0919d7028c78ee63e79593ef689; mage-messages=%5B%5D
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

In Delphi we always got the Accept-Encoding "identity", which we aren't able to delete.
We deleted the Accept-Charset, which is in the request from Delphi but it doesn't make a difference.

Now we don't have any clues what else we can do. Maybe anyone of you had the same problem and could help us? Or maybe one of you has any ideas, what we could try?

Comment: The documentation says "You do have to make a 'GET-request', and the pattern is part of the URL. According to the HTTP standards, this value has to be 'url-encoded' if it contains spaces or other 'special' characters. You can do this on your own, or just use a request-parameter of type 'URL-segment'". Also try to use RESTRequest2.ExecuteAsync instead of RESTRequest2.Execute so the task won't be executed in the same thread as the UI :)

Comment: Read here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/REST_Client_Library#Accessing_a_Simple_API

Comment: @AlbertoMiola

Thanks for your answer. We tried several ways now. We encoded the special characters and spaces by ourselves but we couldn't get any positive result.
With the URL-segment parameters you are able to have parameters in your url, but this isn't necessary, because we build the url with every call by ourselves in different ways.

Maybe anyone has a working code example we could use?